# Generics: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray<subclass *> *' with an expression of type 'NSMutableArray<__kindof superclass *> *

Tags: objective-c, generics

I have this property:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray <__kindof superclass*> *items;
```

I populate it with objects for a subclass (which should be ok due to __kindof). I retrieve the array like this:

```
NSMutableArray <__kindof subclass*> *items = holderObject.items;
```

But now I get this compiler warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray<subclass *> *' with an expression of type 'NSMutableArray<__kindof superclass *> * _Nullable'
```

Isn't this what __kindof is suposed to do for us? What am I doing wrong here?

***UPDATE 2:* This only happens for mutable arrays.**

Update: here is some simple code that show the warning:

Create a new class GenericsError.h:

```
@import UIKit;
@interface GenericsError : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray <__kindof UIViewController*> *generics;
@end
```

In any viewController just add:

```
GenericsError *error = [GenericsError new];
NSMutableArray <ViewController*>* controllers = error.generics;
```

(substitute ViewController for whatever your viewController is called). I'm not adding or creating anything, just getting the compiler warning for the generics-error.

Comment: In my xcode 9.2 that warning doesn't appear. Could you provide more code. As it written here with abstract code it is hard to tell the source of a problem.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I'm using Xcode 10, so it could explain the problem - that it simply is an Apple bug. Will double-check!

Comment: Yes, it's also looks like a bug for me in LLVM. I can only suggest using explicit typecasting with `(typeof(items))`.

Comment: I have 9.4.1 installed and there is the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic parameter of `NSMutableArray` is invariant (it's declared `@interface NSMutableArray<ObjectType>` and not `@interface NSMutableArray<__covariant ObjectType>` or `@interface NSMutableArray<__contravariant ObjectType>`). That means the type argument must match exactly for it to be compatible.

That means `NSMutableArray<NSString *> *` cannot be assigned to `NSMutableArray<NSObject *> *`, or vice versa, even though `NSString *` can be assigned to `NSObject *`. (On the other hand, the type parameter of `NSArray` is covariant (it is declared `NSArray<__covariant ObjectType>`), which means `NSArray<NSString *> *` *can* be assigned to `NSArray<NSObject *> *`.)

`NSMutableArray<NSString *> *` cannot even be assigned to `NSMutableArray<id> *`, or vice versa, even though `NSString *` can be assigned to `id` and `id` can be assigned to `NSString *`, in both directions. I guess the idea is that `id` turns off static type checking, but only on uses of the actual type `id`, and not for types that have `id` as a type argument.

`__kindof superclass *` is kind of a "limited" version of `id` -- it turns off static type checking, but only when assigning to and from subtypes of `superclass *`. For the same reason that `NSMutableArray<id> *` cannot be assigned to or from `NSMutableArray<someclass *> *` above, `NSMutableArray<__kindof superclass *> *` also cannot be assigned to or from `NSMutableArray<subclass *> *`.

Comment: Alright! NSMutableArray are not marked __covariant and then won't accept subclasses (which NSArray are). I think you misunderstood the question, I never wanted to substitute with the superclasses - only subclasses. But you solved it anyway so it doesn't matter! Weird that __covariant is not the default! Generics is much less useful now...

Comment: @Olof_t: It's important for read-and-write classes to be invariant, because otherwise, you can assign a `NSMutableArray<SubClass*>*` variable to a `NSMutableArray<SuperClass*>*` variable, so now you have two pointers to the same array object, and you can then add a `SuperClass*` element which is not an instance of `SubClass` using the `NSMutableArray<SuperClass*>*` variable, and then get it out using the `NSMutableArray<SubClass*>*` variable as a `SubClass*`. Only "producers" (read-only) should be covariant, and only "consumers" (write-only) should be contravariant.

Comment: But that is not in the contract. Sure I can cast the variables or fiddle directly with memory to set or change the objects inside my array. But if I state that I want instances of "SuperClass" in the array, all those and their subclasses should be allowed. If its tampered with of-course it won't work as expected? So the problem is that you can assign a NSMutableArray<SubClass*>* variable to a NSMutableArray<SuperClass*>* variable and not Generics as it is? Then the compiler should complain then and not complain on my Generics? (I think I'm misunderstanding something.)

Answer (score -1):

You have an inheritance **A -> B** (where **A** is the subclass and **B** is the superclass), you declared a container to hold instances of **A** but you are trying to put instances of **B** inside the container. It's not guaranteed that all the instances of **B** are also instances of **A**.

Imagine to have another class **C -> B** (where **C** is a subclass of **B**, and **B** is the same superclass mentioned above). In this case **C** is **__kindof** **B** but it's not **__kindof** **A**, hence the warning.

Long story short: you need to use **__kindof superclass** when declaring your container, to suppress the warning.

Comment: It's not guaranteed, but that is what for what keyword `__kindof` was maid for: implicit typecasting and mean that programmer know what he is doing and can guarantee that.

Comment: Still, you need to make use of the superclass when using __kindof else you'll get the warning. If you define a property to be NSArray<__kindof UIImageView*>*, when you set the property with something like NSArray<__kindof UIView*>* you get the warning (just tried and i got: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSArray<__kindof UIImageView *> *' from 'NSArray<__kindof UIView *> *'.

Comment: Nope, the container is declared to hold B (the superclass), and gets filled with A (the subclass).

Comment: I didn't get warnings with `NSArray<__kindof UIImageView *> *imageViewArray; NSArray<__kindof UIView *> *viewArray; imageViewArray = viewArray;`. But get it when replace `NSArray`'s with `NSMutableArray`